# Function to modify pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of values which I want to add some noise. For that I made this function:

```
def noise(df, noise):
    return np.random.normal(0, df.std() * noise, df.size)
```

And call it with:

```
noise(test_df, 0.15)
```

However it's giving me a shape missmatch error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

A dataframe example:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=list('AB'), dtype=float)
```

I do need my function to have as arguments the dataframe and the noise.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.std()` returns a series, one entry for each column. You need to use `size=df.shape` so you can broadcast that series to the shape, not `df.size`.

Try with:

```
def noise(df, noise, seed=None):
    if seed is not None: np.random.seed(seed)
    return np.random.normal(0, df.std() * noise,size=df.shape)

noise(test_df, 0.15, seed=43)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.05460277, -0.19271801],
       [-0.08029263, -0.11347273]])
```